# Magento 2: how to get json posted data in payment method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, json

Magento is posting payment detail in json format on **rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information**

**Method post**

```
{"cartId":"3","billingAddress":{"countryId":"US","regionId":"0","postcode":null,"saveInAddressBook":null
},"paymentMethod":{"method":"test_method","additional_data":{"testing":"abcdef"
,"temail":"test@test.com"}}}
```

how to get **additional data** in my **validation** method

```
public function validate()
      {
          /*
           * calling parent validate function
           */
          parent::validate();

          return $this;
      }
```

Comment: You want to get the post data from your custom js validation?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh This is php validation method in payment model.

Comment: Try with,validate(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $data){
$additionalData = $data->getData()['additional_data'];
}

Comment: @QaisarSatti Which is your Magento version?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh  Magento ver. 2.1.6

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no way to directly access the parameters via API (we tried to do that but failed). However, we've found an alternative method to get them.

As you probably know, an API request is also classifed as 'Request', and the parameters are anyway sent to it and stored in the `processApiRequest` method. If you have a closer look at it, you'll see that the `\Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver` deals with the request parameters. Hence, we can use it to extract the needed parameters from the API request.

Add the class `\Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver` to the di (dependency injection) of your payment class in the `validate` method.

You'll get the parameters in the following way:

```
$inputParams = $inputParamsResolver->resolve();
```

The result of your request will look somewhat like this (in my example, it was implemented on the Check Money Order method):

[image: https://gyazo.com/576545c62d2011140bf5ee6c6ee903d4]

additional_data can be found in the instance `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment`.

[image]

These parameters are exactly the same, as those that are sent to a method called via API:

[image]

Just note that this approach has some pitfalls. The parameters come raw, in the array, so you'll have to sort them to find the needed ones.

P.S. If to take the quote payment directly from the quote available via payment info method,

```
$paymentInfo = $this->getInfoInstance();
$additionalData = $paymentInfo->getQuote()->getPayment()->getData('additional_data');
```

it's possible to see that the parameter from the request is not there.

[image]

Comment: the recommended solution didn't work for me. I was trying to get the payment additional data in observer which was called after a order was created using the REST API.